# How do I get a package from nuget, even if a project with the same name is available in the solution?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, dnx, .net-core, project.json

I have a solution with several projects, all of which are DNX class libraries that emit nuget packages. Our build server adds versioning info in appropriate places to `project.json` and `AssemlyInfo`, packages all these projects in one go by building the solution, and then uploads them to a private NuGet feed. That all works gallantly.

However, some of these projects have dependencies on each-other. I would like to resolve them by actually adding nuget packages from the feed, rather than just referencing the project directly (if for no other reason, then because the dependency spec should reference the correct version, but I get a bunch of warnings about incorrect assembly versions since that step isn't done until on the build server).

How do I specify that project A depends on NuGet package B, even if there is a project named B in the same solution?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, that's not possible in dnx.

I would argue that since you have a scenario like that, you should split your solution in two or more smaller solutions. That's exactly what we, the ASP.NET, did by splitting our codebase in multiple repos and get dependencies through feeds.